# Is there a way I can combine 2 lists and an array into a multidictionary?

Tags: python, optimization, gurobi

I have the following data:

```py
from gurobipy import multidict

P = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'] #Projects
S = ['A','B','C','D','E','F'] #Subcontractors


C = np.array([[29, 49, 45, 55, 44, 49, 50, 45, 59],
              [46, 57, 59, 56, 30, 34, 42, 36, 49],
              [55, 42, 44, 46,9, 49, 29, 22, 34],
              [56, 55, 11,35,24,32,57,40,38],
              [37,37,54,44,22,52,47,10,22],
              [34,51,38,34,37,43,36,58,44]])

 #Costs - row is for Subcon and Columns is for Project
```

I am trying to transform the above to a multi dictionary that combines  Project/Subcontractor to its cost like the below:

```py
combination, cost = multidict({
    ('A','1'): 29,
    ('A','2'): 49,
    ('A','3'): 45,
    ('A','4'): 55,
    ('A','5'): 44,
    ('A','6'): 49,
    ('A','7'): 50,
    ('A','8'): 45,
    ('A','9'): 49}
)
```

Answer (score 0):

First combine P and S the way you want. next use zip to convert into Zip.:

```
import numpy as np

P = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'] #Projects
S = ['A','B','C','D','E','F'] #Subcontractors


C = np.array([[29, 49, 45, 55, 44, 49, 50, 45, 59],
              [46, 57, 59, 56, 30, 34, 42, 36, 49],
              [55, 42, 44, 46,9, 49, 29, 22, 34],
              [56, 55, 11,35,24,32,57,40,38],
              [37,37,54,44,22,52,47,10,22],
              [34,51,38,34,37,43,36,58,44]])

final=[]
for s in S:
    temp=[]
    for p in P:
        temp.append(*zip(s,p))
    final.append(temp)

output=[dict(zip(x, c)) for c in C for x in final]           
print(output)
```

And the output will be

```
[{('A', '1'): 29, ('A', '2'): 49, ('A', '3'): 45, ('A', '4'): 55, ('A', '5'): 44, ('A', '6'): 49, ('A', '7'): 50, ('A', '8'): 45, ('A', '9'): 59}, {('B', '1'): 29, ('B', '2'): 49, ('B', '3'): 45, ('B', '4'): 55, ('B', '5'): 44, ('B', '6'): 49, ('B', '7'): 50, ('B', '8'): 45, ('B', '9'): 59}, {('C', '1'): 29, ('C', '2'): 49, ('C', '3'): 45, ('C', '4'): 55, ('C', '5'): 44, ('C', '6'): 49, ('C', '7'): 50, ('C', '8'): 45, ('C', '9'): 59}, {('D', '1'): 29, ('D', '2'): 49, ('D', '3'): 45, ('D', '4'): 55, ('D', '5'): 44, ('D', '6'): 49, ('D', '7'): 50, ('D', '8'): 45, ('D', '9'): 59}, {('E', '1'): 29, ('E', '2'): 49, ('E', '3'): 45, ('E', '4'): 55, ('E', '5'): 44, ('E', '6'): 49, ('E', '7'): 50, ('E', '8'): 45, ('E', '9'): 59}, {('F', '1'): 29, ('F', '2'): 49, ('F', '3'): 45, ('F', '4'): 55, ('F', '5'): 44, ('F', '6'): 49, ('F', '7'): 50, ('F', '8'): 45, ('F', '9'): 59}, {('A', '1'): 46, ('A', '2'): 57, ('A', '3'): 59, ('A', '4'): 56, ('A', '5'): 30, ('A', '6'): 34, ('A', '7'): 42, ('A', '8'): 36, ('A', '9'): 49}, {('B', '1'): 46, ('B', '2'): 57, ('B', '3'): 59, ('B', '4'): 56, ('B', '5'): 30, ('B', '6'): 34, ('B', '7'): 42, ('B', '8'): 36, ('B', '9'): 49}, {('C', '1'): 46, ('C', '2'): 57, ('C', '3'): 59, ('C', '4'): 56, ('C', '5'): 30, ('C', '6'): 34, ('C', '7'): 42, ('C', '8'): 36, ('C', '9'): 49}, {('D', '1'): 46, ('D', '2'): 57, ('D', '3'): 59, ('D', '4'): 56, ('D', '5'): 30, ('D', '6'): 34, ('D', '7'): 42, ('D', '8'): 36, ('D', '9'): 49}, {('E', '1'): 46, ('E', '2'): 57, ('E', '3'): 59, ('E', '4'): 56, ('E', '5'): 30, ('E', '6'): 34, ('E', '7'): 42, ('E', '8'): 36, ('E', '9'): 49}, {('F', '1'): 46, ('F', '2'): 57, ('F', '3'): 59, ('F', '4'): 56, ('F', '5'): 30, ('F', '6'): 34, ('F', '7'): 42, ('F', '8'): 36, ('F', '9'): 49}, {('A', '1'): 55, ('A', '2'): 42, ('A', '3'): 44, ('A', '4'): 46, ('A', '5'): 9, ('A', '6'): 49, ('A', '7'): 29, ('A', '8'): 22, ('A', '9'): 34}, {('B', '1'): 55, ('B', '2'): 42, ('B', '3'): 44, ('B', '4'): 46, ('B', '5'): 9, ('B', '6'): 49, ('B', '7'): 29, ('B', '8'): 22, ('B', '9'): 34}, {('C', '1'): 55, ('C', '2'): 42, ('C', '3'): 44, ('C', '4'): 46, ('C', '5'): 9, ('C', '6'): 49, ('C', '7'): 29, ('C', '8'): 22, ('C', '9'): 34}, {('D', '1'): 55, ('D', '2'): 42, ('D', '3'): 44, ('D', '4'): 46, ('D', '5'): 9, ('D', '6'): 49, ('D', '7'): 29, ('D', '8'): 22, ('D', '9'): 34}, {('E', '1'): 55, ('E', '2'): 42, ('E', '3'): 44, ('E', '4'): 46, ('E', '5'): 9, ('E', '6'): 49, ('E', '7'): 29, ('E', '8'): 22, ('E', '9'): 34}, {('F', '1'): 55, ('F', '2'): 42, ('F', '3'): 44, ('F', '4'): 46, ('F', '5'): 9, ('F', '6'): 49, ('F', '7'): 29, ('F', '8'): 22, ('F', '9'): 34}, {('A', '1'): 56, ('A', '2'): 55, ('A', '3'): 11, ('A', '4'): 35, ('A', '5'): 24, ('A', '6'): 32, ('A', '7'): 57, ('A', '8'): 40, ('A', '9'): 38}, {('B', '1'): 56, ('B', '2'): 55, ('B', '3'): 11, ('B', '4'): 35, ('B', '5'): 24, ('B', '6'): 32, ('B', '7'): 57, ('B', '8'): 40, ('B', '9'): 38}, {('C', '1'): 56, ('C', '2'): 55, ('C', '3'): 11, ('C', '4'): 35, ('C', '5'): 24, ('C', '6'): 32, ('C', '7'): 57, ('C', '8'): 40, ('C', '9'): 38}, {('D', '1'): 56, ('D', '2'): 55, ('D', '3'): 11, ('D', '4'): 35, ('D', '5'): 24, ('D', '6'): 32, ('D', '7'): 57, ('D', '8'): 40, ('D', '9'): 38}, {('E', '1'): 56, ('E', '2'): 55, ('E', '3'): 11, ('E', '4'): 35, ('E', '5'): 24, ('E', '6'): 32, ('E', '7'): 57, ('E', '8'): 40, ('E', '9'): 38}, {('F', '1'): 56, ('F', '2'): 55, ('F', '3'): 11, ('F', '4'): 35, ('F', '5'): 24, ('F', '6'): 32, ('F', '7'): 57, ('F', '8'): 40, ('F', '9'): 38}, {('A', '1'): 37, ('A', '2'): 37, ('A', '3'): 54, ('A', '4'): 44, ('A', '5'): 22, ('A', '6'): 52, ('A', '7'): 47, ('A', '8'): 10, ('A', '9'): 22}, {('B', '1'): 37, ('B', '2'): 37, ('B', '3'): 54, ('B', '4'): 44, ('B', '5'): 22, ('B', '6'): 52, ('B', '7'): 47, ('B', '8'): 10, ('B', '9'): 22}, {('C', '1'): 37, ('C', '2'): 37, ('C', '3'): 54, ('C', '4'): 44, ('C', '5'): 22, ('C', '6'): 52, ('C', '7'): 47, ('C', '8'): 10, ('C', '9'): 22}, {('D', '1'): 37, ('D', '2'): 37, ('D', '3'): 54, ('D', '4'): 44, ('D', '5'): 22, ('D', '6'): 52, ('D', '7'): 47, ('D', '8'): 10, ('D', '9'): 22}, {('E', '1'): 37, ('E', '2'): 37, ('E', '3'): 54, ('E', '4'): 44, ('E', '5'): 22, ('E', '6'): 52, ('E', '7'): 47, ('E', '8'): 10, ('E', '9'): 22}, {('F', '1'): 37, ('F', '2'): 37, ('F', '3'): 54, ('F', '4'): 44, ('F', '5'): 22, ('F', '6'): 52, ('F', '7'): 47, ('F', '8'): 10, ('F', '9'): 22}, {('A', '1'): 34, ('A', '2'): 51, ('A', '3'): 38, ('A', '4'): 34, ('A', '5'): 37, ('A', '6'): 43, ('A', '7'): 36, ('A', '8'): 58, ('A', '9'): 44}, {('B', '1'): 34, ('B', '2'): 51, ('B', '3'): 38, ('B', '4'): 34, ('B', '5'): 37, ('B', '6'): 43, ('B', '7'): 36, ('B', '8'): 58, ('B', '9'): 44}, {('C', '1'): 34, ('C', '2'): 51, ('C', '3'): 38, ('C', '4'): 34, ('C', '5'): 37, ('C', '6'): 43, ('C', '7'): 36, ('C', '8'): 58, ('C', '9'): 44}, {('D', '1'): 34, ('D', '2'): 51, ('D', '3'): 38, ('D', '4'): 34, ('D', '5'): 37, ('D', '6'): 43, ('D', '7'): 36, ('D', '8'): 58, ('D', '9'): 44}, {('E', '1'): 34, ('E', '2'): 51, ('E', '3'): 38, ('E', '4'): 34, ('E', '5'): 37, ('E', '6'): 43, ('E', '7'): 36, ('E', '8'): 58, ('E', '9'): 44}, {('F', '1'): 34, ('F', '2'): 51, ('F', '3'): 38, ('F', '4'): 34, ('F', '5'): 37, ('F', '6'): 43, ('F', '7'): 36, ('F', '8'): 58, ('F', '9'): 44}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a dict-comprehension, you can do it with an one-liner:

```
from gurobipy import multidict
combination, cost = multidict({comb: c for comb, c in zip(((s,p) for p in P for s in S), C.ravel())})
```

where

- `((s,p) for p in P for s in S)` creates the combination tuples
- `C.ravel()` returns a view to the flattened array
- `zip()` aggegrates the two previous iterables